# Tcl error in xilinx isim simulator

Tags: tcl, xilinx

I am trying to write a tcl script for some simulations in isim. the script would run two nested loops and generate a file in each iteration. when running the simulation with this scrips the simulator generates the error:

```
 TCL batch file "D:...subbyte.tcl" encountered an error in line 2. Simulator is exiting.
```

but all the output files are generated and saved. I am totally confused with it.
Thanks for any help in advance!

```
run 100 ns
for {set i 0} { $i<1} {incr i} {

    for {set j 0} { $j<256} {incr j} {
        saif open -scope uut -file "saifsubbyte $i$j .saif" -allnets
        run 1 ns
        saif close
        run 19 ns
    }

}
```

Comment: Is that _all_ the error information it is giving? It's rather uninformative, and the script as you wrote it doesn't look wrong (provided there's a `run` command defined, etc.)…

Comment: Thanks.The error message is all I see in isim console...and besides I've already used "run" command in such scripts.